# Multiple Foreign Keys with Wordpress core database `wp_blogs`

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress

Currently I have a multi-site WordPress that have 6 sub-sites at the moment. My question/worry is that, is it a bad design to have 10+ tables foreign-ed key to `wp_blogs` on its primary key?

I did it this way so that when a sub-site is deleted it will also delete the data that the site has made through my custom functions.

Comment: I think better practice would be to write custom delete statements corresponding to your custom functions when site is deleted

Comment: after reading your comment, I feel like some sun ray flashed on me and cleanse my uneasiness with the way how I approach deletion... Thanks a lot Bridget :)